Нужно ли поставить тире перед фразой "вдвое больше" в предложении:
В прошлом году в Кизнере велопарад собрал рекордное число участников – 2150, вдвое больше, чем годом ранее!
Или перед цифрой надо поставить запятую вместо тире? И все равно, нужно ли тире перед "вдвое", даже если ставим перед цифрой запятую вместо тире?

Часть предложения (вдвое больше, чем...) дана без союза или подлежащего. В него хотелось бы внести изменения: Велопарад собрал рекордное число участников — 2150, что вдвое больше, чем годом ранее. Или: Велопарад собрал рекордное число участников — 2150, а это вдвое больше, чем годом ранее.

Спасибо большое! Работа уже сдана, и я так и сделала - вставила "что" перед вдвое.
